# NIO non-blocking mode

Tags: java, nonblocking

One of the most important aspects of NIO is the ability to operate in non-blocking mode, denied to the traditional java I/O library. But what is non-blocking mode?

Comment: I usually use NIO in blocking mode esp for files, and sometimes for Sockets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Asynchronous** I/O, or **non-blocking** I/O, is a form of input/output processing that permits other processing to continue before the transmission has finished.